# java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package com.unboundid.ldap.sdk is sealed

Tags: java, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I am deploying a WAR file to remote server, and getting below security exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package com.unboundid.ldap.sdk is sealed
```

The same WAR file is working fine in local environment using Tomcat8.

Please assist where to include the unboundid ldap jar file. Either in WEB-INF/lib or as an external one.

Thanks.

Comment: Any inputs please...

Comment: Do you have multiple copies of the JAR file?

Comment: @EJP no, I have included single jar file...

Comment: Is it required to setup the .classpath externally...